# Simplifying expression in iterator biding to ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ngmodel

I have arrived at a lengthy syntax iterating over *data[areaId].main.points*. Since the data is bound via *[(ngModel)]*, it looks atrociously in my opinion. Something like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data[areaId].main.points; let index = index; let ..." ...>
  <input [(ngModel)]="data[areaId].main.points[index].e" ... >
  <input [(ngModel)]="data[areaId].main.points[index].n" ... >
  ...
</div>
```

Usually, when the syntax gets ugly, it's a strong indication that the design sucks and should be simplified. Not always. But in most cases. So I wonder if there's a syntax setting the *data-main-points* thing to something locally defined and shorter. One option might be to declare an auxilliary field in the model only keeping a portion of the whole data and bind to it. However, I sense that there's a better way to approach it.

How should I simplify the expression so that the iterator can reder and the *ngModel* can keep an eye on its changes?

Comment: you can use `[(ngModel)]="item.e"`

Comment: @Eliseo Are you certain? I'm going to give it a go immediately, of course. However, it seems to me that it's going to mix together the different *item* instances into one in the model. If it does work, I'll have a very good question on how the iterator is able to discriminate *item* from *item* when they are referring to different *index* values, hence different positions in the main array.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You know, you could ask the same question about the `index` you're using. How do you know which `index` you using at any given time? Angular can figure it out, doesn't matter that they have same name, each `item` refers to something different. You can safely use it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, each "item" has its own "scope" inside the loop. Always the items was **objects** you has no problem. if the "items" are simple element you can not use it. Example, NOT work `values=[1,2,3];<input *ngFor="let value of values" [(ngModel)]="value">`, work `values=[{a:1},{a:2}];<input *ngFor="let value of values" [(ngModel)]="value.a">`

Comment: @Eliseo I can confirm - you're perfectly right. Both in regard to *item* being the shortest syntax working **and** in regards to the simple element not working (which was the case while I was playing around to create a POC). Please post it the answer so I can accept it.