# How to control the type of value bound using ngModel (number gets distorted to string)?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngmodel

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027413/simplifying-expression-in-iterator-biding-to-ngmodel?noredirect=1#comment106160639_60027413) and got it working. However, I notice that although the data provided consists of objects declared like this:

```
export interface GisPoint { e: number; n: number; }
```

when the user enters a value, the original contents being *{ e: 12, n: 34 }* become string'ish, i.e. *{ e: "123", n: 34 }*. I understand that the result from the input will be assumed a string so I'll have to convert it. However, as the binding goes through *ngModel*, I actually don't react explicitly to *keyUp* or *blur*.

Do I have to explicitly do that? If so, there's really no point using  *ngModel*. It would be quite nifty to be able to keep the type when the edited value gets entered.

Comment: if you specify in your html markup the input element's type like `<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="data.age">` then it will stay in your model as number

Comment: @robert Wouldn't that generate an input box with up and down arrows, like a ticker box? I believe the implication of setting *type="number"* is precisely that. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). Also you can hide them with some [css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/).

Comment: @robert My comment disappeared and I'm worried that there's been a misunderstanding. I asked about that [here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393521/what-happened-to-my-comment) and I hope that you didn't took offence for a clumsy formulated thoughts of mine. Did you?

Comment: No offence is taken. I posted my comments as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface for the Component, so that you specify which value represents the model.

Here's a couple good articles to start from:

- https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf
- https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/

Comment: Good suggestion. Just to verify that I got you correctly. You're saying that I implement my own control that harbors an input as a part of its template, right? My understanding is that I can't impose a logic of a custom value accessor on a default input control. Am I mistaken? That's what I gathered from the linked article too. What's you take on that?

Comment: Correct. You will need to create a custom control which implement the ControlValueAccessor. In your case it would most likely wrap a standard Input component. I added another article that might help you.

Comment: For now, I'm going to loop through all the arrays and go *a[i]=+a[i]* because I'm in a bit of hurry and I worry that introducing a custom control will bump me into delays. (I'm stressed as a pair of bull's balls during spring season, hehe.) But next week, I definitely will do some better quality setup.

Answer (score 2):

Given this HTML markup:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="data.age">
```

You will get the desired number in your model. Angular will not convert it to a string. One "side effect" is that browser will add these number spinners.

The easiest way to hide them is to use a small css rule:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

More info on css [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp).

Check this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6sbeb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).